# How to trigger ViewModel Methods from Model in MVVM Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am new to WPF and MWWM I am using Caliburn Micro. I have managed to mage a GUI to setup the port and open it and I know how to handle the received data from COM port in Winform but I dont know how to link my received data to the ViewModel in WPF all COM related code is in a Model Class but really the question is when Datarecived handler is triggered how can I notify the view and viewmodel
you help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please, share what have you tried so far

Comment: did you create an object of your model inside the viewmodel class ? and use that object to bind to the view.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the `EventAggregator`. You can broadcast a message to all view models and the relevant view model can then subscribe to messages they are interested in. See the [Caliburn Micro Docs](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/event-aggregator) for more information.

One problem you may need to overcome depends upon how pure you wish to keep your model. I personally don't like to have any dependencies on Caliburn Micro inside my models. I keep them in a separate assembly to make sure that cannot happen. You would then require a mechanism to tell your view model about events happening inside your model. You could use regular .NET events to link data being received from your serial port to the view model. The view model could then use the event aggregator to send the message to all interested view models.